# Python gives error message "BufferedAsyncWriter write too large \n write header failed"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've built a script that makes two parallelized process over the same text files, each one saving results into a new text file with a proper file name. One of these process does it well, while another gives error message from question title.

I thought it was because I save results in a buffer and then I write it completely into the file, so I've change this part of code such that each new results line generated would be immediately saved on file, and nonetheless error message still appears, and so I can't get results saved on file.

I'm now testing a new version of script with processes unparalleled, but how could I solve this problem such that I could keep processes parallelized?

Here's the sample code below:

```
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

    def process():
        counter_object_results = make_data_processing()
        txt_file_name = f'file_name.txt'

        with open(txt_file_name, 'a') as txt_file:
            for count in counter_object_results.items():
                txt_file_content = f'{counter_object_results[0]}\t{counter_object_results[1]}\n'
                txt_file.write(txt_file_content)


    def process_2():
        counter_object_results = make_data_processing()
        txt_file_name = f'file_name.txt'

        with open(txt_file_name, 'a') as txt_file:
            for count in counter_object_results.items():
                txt_file_content = f'{counter_object_results[0]}\t{counter_object_results[1]}\n'
                txt_file.write(txt_file_content)

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        worker_a = executor.submit(process)
        worker_b = executor.submit(process_2)
        futures = [worker_a, worker_b]

        for worker in as_completed(futures):
            resp = worker.result()
            print(f'Results saved on {resp}')
```

Comment: We also really need the traceback. The object type in the error message indicates that the error originated from somewhere else as `open()` would not produce that object type.

Comment: That's the point. There is no traceback error message, just that error message.

Comment: Actually, there is no `BufferedAsyncWriter` type in the Python standard library, anywhere. What else can you tell us about your environment here?

Comment: I'm running this code on Python 3.6, using pure python, and at most a library called Biopython.

Comment: Additional info: this code is run on a shared-use 40-core machine with 220GB of RAM (it is a machine from university where I study). Input file has 0,5GB, producing temporary files with hundreds of MB of data. Each temp file are read and processed such that a dict is formed. This dict is saved onto a results file using a code similar with question's code.